# What's the correct way of using CSS3 font-face?

Tags: css, font-face

Could someone please help me understand what's the correct way of using CSS3 font-face. Below are some font-face declarations, which one is correct and why?

```
/* START OF SAMPLE CODE # 1 */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot');
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('webfont.svg#WebFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebFont';
    src: url('webfont-bold.eot');
    src: url('webfont-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfont-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfont-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('webfont-bold.svg#WebFont-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'WebFont', blah, blah, blah;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'WebFont', blah, blah, blah;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* END OF SAMPLE CODE # 1 */
```

=========

```
/* START OF SAMPLE CODE # 2 */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot');
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('webfont.svg#WebFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebFontBold';
    src: url('webfont-bold.eot');
    src: url('webfont-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfont-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfont-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('webfont-bold.svg#WebFont-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'WebFontBold', blah, blah, blah;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'WebFont', blah, blah, blah;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* END OF SAMPLE CODE # 2 */
```

=========

```
/* START OF SAMPLE CODE # 3 */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot');
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('webfont.svg#WebFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebFontBold';
    src: url('webfont-bold.eot');
    src: url('webfont-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfont-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfont-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('webfont-bold.svg#WebFont-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'WebFontBold', blah, blah, blah;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'WebFont', blah, blah, blah;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* END OF SAMPLE CODE # 3 */
```

The difference in these code samples, is the way "Bold" font is being declared and used. Please advise, which one is correct from these and why?

PS: I am sorry for such a long question/sample. I just wanted to provide as much information as I could to avoid confusion.

> Edit 1: Even though as mentioned by @Jukka in one of the answers below, the logical approach is to use "Code #1", but I just checked Safari and the bold font renders way too much bolder on Safari as compared to other browsers, but if I use "Code #2" all browsers render the same, so it does appear that there is something going on behind the scenes when using different font-face declarations. So at this moment I seem "Code #2" is the way to go, what say!

Comment: any of this is working?

Comment: I used chrome and firefox and ie8 and all three of them are working, that's why I am confused which one to use!

Comment: @font-face{
 font-family:Mysegoi;
    src: url('../fonts/segoeui.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/segoeui.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/segoeui.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/segoeui.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/helveticaneue-medium-webfont.svg#HelveticaNeue65Medium') format('svg');
   
 }

Comment: you can use any one, this is one best method i used to do

Comment: if you want to use bold, download the particular bold font and add

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, but you seem to have missed the point. I have the bold font! What I want to understand.. Is it better to have the "bold" font (or any other font-style/variation for that matter) declared as a separate font-face-family name like "WebFontBold" or use the existing font-face-family name and add a new declaration with required font-style/weight etc.

Comment: You need to use seperate font family for BOLD

Comment: You should provide an actual demo (with a real font) to show how code #1 fails in Safari. This sounds like an error in the way of telling that a typeface is bold, making Safari apply algorithmic bolding to an already bold typeface.

Answer (score 1):

None of the codes is correct, since quotation marks are not allowed around the keywords `bold` and `normal` according to CSS syntax. Otherwise, code 1 is based on logical principles, since it specifies two typefaces, normal and bold, as being of the same font family, as they apparently are. The other codes declare each typeface as if it were a font family. Used with due caution, this approach works, too.

The main practical difference is that using the logical approach (code 1), you could simply declare `font-family: WebFont, Foobar`, even for all elements if you like, and the bold typeface would automatically be used for those elements that have `font-weight: bold` set on them (by browser defaults, like for `h1`, or by explicit setting). This also means that if the WebFont font family is not used for some reason (like browser setting that rejects downloadable fonts), the appropriate typeface (normal or bold) of the Foobar font would be used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but that was just a typo in the sample code.