# How to use outside fonts in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts

I have downloaded a folder full of svg and otf-files. They contain a font that I would like to use in my html-document. Here's what the folder looks like:

[image: fonts-folder contains all of the different files.]

First question:

Which of the files should I use? I understand that "process.svg" and "process-yellow.svg" probably have different colors, BUT, when we have one "process-yellow.svg" and one "process-yellow.otf", which one should I use?

Second question:

How do I use the font in my HTML document? So far I've tried this:

In the html16.html style-element:

```
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family:'Process';
            src: url('/fonts/process.svg#process') format('svg');
        }

        p.text1 {
            width: 140px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            word-break: keep-all;
            font-family: 'Process';
        }
</style>
```

In the html16.html body-element:

```
<body>
    <b>word-break:keep-all</b>
    <p class="text1">Tutorials Point originated from the idea that there exists-a class of readers who respond better to online content and prefer to learn new skills at their own pace from the comforts of their drawing rooms.</p>

</body>
```

But it doesn't do anything to the font. It just looks like it would look without me changing the font.

EDIT: It should be added that importing woff-fonts works for me, like I did here:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:Process;
    src: url(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/font/SansationLight.woff);
}
```

Comment: The first part of the question is like saying you've downloaded a dozen logos in PNG format and asking which one you should use—how could we possibly know? Look back at whatever site you've grabbed them from and see if downloads include documentation or information of any kind.

Comment: Do a CTRL + F5 to hard refresh your browser. If that doesn't work, check your src url (when you view your source code, check that the url points to the correct place).

Comment: No success with that, Stanley. URL is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way of using CSS3 font-face?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998167/whats-the-correct-way-of-using-css3-font-face)

Comment: If your `fonts` folder and CSS file are placed in a same level, don't use started slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If web embedding is allowed. You can generate other font type files [from here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), which works for the older browsers.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Process';
    src: url('/fonts/process.eot') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/fonts/process.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/fonts/process.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/fonts/process.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('/fonts/process.svg#process') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Not interested in generating my own font. I want to learn how to import fonts.

Comment: It is not generator it is converter. You have to convert the current svg and otf font files to other format such as eot, woff, ttf to work with other browsers.

Comment: Do you mean that SVG format has never been supported by major browsers?

Comment: Correct, check Browser Support from https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Please check with below syntax.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: novalight;
   src: url('/static/src/fonts/novalight.otf');
}

.proximanovalight {
   font-family : novalight, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Used your syntax but with my own file- and fontnames. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This - Import like so,

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=El+Messiri');
```

Then use:

```
font-family: 'El Messiri', sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was the following:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Titilum';
        src: url('fonts/Titillium_Web/TitilliumWeb-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    }


    .pftop {
        font-family: Titilum;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```